# Ajax resending XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've got a client side js/ajax script like this:

```
<p>server  time  is:  <strong  id="stime">Please  wait...</strong></p>

<script>
function  updateAjax()  {
    xmlhttp  =  new  XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  =  function()  {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==3  &&  xmlhttp.status==200)  {
            document.getElementById("stime").innerHTML=
            xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        if  (xmlhttp.readyState==4)  {  
            xmlhttp.open("GET","date-sleep.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","date-sleep.php",true);  
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.setTimeout("updateAjax();",100);
</script>
```

And a on the server side:

```
<?php
    echo  6;
    for  ($i=0;  $i<10;  $i++)  {
        echo  $i;
        ob_flush();  flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
?>
```

After first 'open' and 'send' it works ok, but when the server finishes the script and `xmlhttp.readyState == 4` then the xmlhttp resends the request but nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of re-using the same XHR object all the time, try repeating the function with a new object. This should at least fix incompatibility issues as you listed.

Try re-calling your Ajax function inside the callback of it, if you want to loop it infinitely.

```
if  (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {  
     updateAjax(); //or setTimeout("updateAjax();",100); if you want a delay
}
```

I'd also suggest putting your `.innerHTML` method inside the [`.readyState==4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is when the requested document has completely loaded, and [`.status==200`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html) which means success. Like this:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4  &&  xmlhttp.status==200) {
       document.getElementById("stime").innerHTML=
       xmlhttp.responseText;
       updateAjax(); //or setTimeout("updateAjax();",100);
}
```

Also, if you want your Ajax to be cross-browser, you should test if the browser supports the [XHR object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) which you're using:

```
var xmlhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

I just typed the code above but it should work just fine to add compatibility with older versions of IE and other browsers.

Comment: I figured out, that it works in Iceweasel. I suppose that it's not working properly because of some firefox caching. Modifying innerHTML in that 'if' block will change the behaviour of script, which should update page always after server sends next data, not only when the connection become closed.

Comment: My solution above is cross-browser, except that you didn't test the browser's XHR object properly. I'll add it to the answer as well.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 your firefox and give a try to my script. It should do exactly what you want and be cross-browser compatible, if not, try to reproduce your problem in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or another live scenery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is just some example code from my classes so cross browser compatibility is not so important.

Comment: Ok I see. Disconsider the cross-browser code part then, my code above should at very least loop infinitely as your question implies. If you need the `.readyState==3`, use only my first block of code in the answer. Tell me if you have any problems with the code after. =]