# how to properly reset XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm sending an AJAX request, receiving a response and replacing some text based on that response. I think I am missing some basic concept here.

```
request.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
    let newCard = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    // replace content.
    request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // I'm trying to reset the request here.
    request.open('POST', '/viewed', true);
  } else {
    console.log('Error ' + request.status + ' text: ' + request.responseText);
  }
}

request.open('POST', '/viewed', true);

// $close is an element on the page.
$close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  request.send(params);
});
```

The result here is on the first click I get new content, but then on the second click I get no new content, then on the third click I get an AJAX error.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.

I'm guessing that trying to reset the `request` inside the *if* block is where I'm falling down, I'm just not sure where/how to do it properly.

Comment: The new xhr object doesn't have an `onreadystatechange` event handler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax resending XMLHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874809/ajax-resending-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: BTW I know this is isn't code review but technically your *else* block will be evaluated for states 1-3 (refer to [XMLHttpRequest.readyState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState).... and those aren't technically errors, as your log statement implies...

Answer (score 0):

What are trying to achieve with the xmlhttp request calls is not clear.  If you want onclick send the request, then set event listener on an element for the request call.

Comment: I've update the code to make more clear `$close` is an element on the page.

Comment: @icicleking do you mean there is code like `var $close = document.getElementById('close');`?

Comment: @Devqxz: He told you, it's an element. Why does that matter? The problem is clearly not related to that variable since the click handler works.

Answer (score 0):

Props to Sam Onela and squint, both answers pointed me in the correct direction. Mostly I needed to set a handler for the new XMLHttpRequestObject. The link provided gave me the basic framework:

```
function updateCard() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = () => {
  if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      let newCard = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      // updating element
     } else {
       console.log('Error ' + request.status + ' text: ' + request.responseText);
     }
  }
  request.open('POST', '/viewed', true);
  request.send(params);
}

$close.addEventListener('click', function() {
  updateCard();
});
```

Comment: FYI, you can do `$close.addEventListener('click', updateCard)`. Also, no need to prefix variables with `$`. It's an odd habit some people seem to have.

Comment: yeah, the dollar sign was to clarify that it's a DOM element in response to another question. Thanks for the more terse syntax.